# Powering Waterpump Low Voltage Water Pump from Arduino Micro 5 Volt pin

Tags: arduino, power-supply, mosfet, heat

I'm thinking about powering 3 Low Voltage 5 Volt submersible pump consecutively with an Arduino micro.
Those cheap pumps draw 100-200mA and the 5 Volt Pin from the Arduino Micro can supply that (i think).
I'm not thinking about powering all pumps at the same time .. only one at a time.

When using those 3 Pumps together with 3 Mosfets to consecutively trigger this 3 pumps, are there any problems to except for the arduino or should I go with an external power supply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB 2.0 and below specification only supplies a total of 500mA. Worst case on your pump estimate is 600mA so you should go with an external power supply.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Arduino Micro can source max 100mA combined for all pins, but even if your pump motors draw that continuously there may still be a high inrush current when they first turn on before they get up to speed. Either way you're probably going to want a separate power supply even if you're only running one at a time.